# Android java Exoplayer layout add view chat message

Tags: java, android, layout, exoplayer

I have to do something like this:

[image]

At the moment the graphics of my player is like this:

[image]

How can I create such a thing?

Some advice?

Comment: Can you be more detailed about which thing you are referencing to in the video / gif ?

Comment: @Harneev: The gif is a player that I made myself, based on exoplayer as a base.